# Handling both Click and Double Click using Reactive.NET RX

Tags: c#, .net, observable, system.reactive

I have a WPF Button in .NET and I wish to handle both the click and double click events separately.  I've currently got this working using Timeouts/Delays and it works but its ugly. I'm trying to find a neat way to do it using System.Reactive extensions for .NET

The Observables are created from a factory method where I pass the button, and I use the FromEventPattern(button, "click") method.  e.g:

```
    public IObservable<EventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>> SingleClickTestObservable(Button button)
    {
        return Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(button, "Click");
    }

    public IObservable<EventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>> DoubleClickTestObservable(Button button)
    {
        return Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(button, "DoubleClick");
    }
```

The problem is when I subscribe to these Observables, the SingleClick fires for both single and double click.

How can make this work as intended, so that when a double click is triggered, a single click is not.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with is to bind to the click events in both examples, and to place events into a 350ms buffer. And then filter based on the number of events that occurred during the 350ms time period.

For a single click event we expect to have 1 click event in the buffer, and for a double click event we expect to have exactly 2:

```
    public IObservable<EventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>> DoubleClickTestObservable(Button button)
    {
        var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(button, "Click");
        var bufferedObservable = observable.Buffer(observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(350)))
            .Select(list => new { list.Count, list })
            .Where(result => result.Count == 2)
            .Select(x => x.list.Last());
        return bufferedObservable;

    }

    public IObservable<EventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>> SingleClickTestObservable(Button button)
    {
        var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(button, "Click");
        var bufferedObservable = observable.Buffer(observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(350)))
            .Select(list => new { list.Count, list })
            .Where(result => result.Count == 1)
            .Select(x => x.list.Single());
        return bufferedObservable;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var button = GetMyButton();         
var singleClickSub = DoubleClickTestObservable(button)
    .Subscribe(pattern => { _logger.Debug("got double click"); });
var doubleClickSub = SingleClickTestObservable(button)
    .Subscribe(pattern => { _logger.Debug("got single click"); });
```

***Note:** _logger is a custom class of mine, replace with alert, or other output method for testing.*

Comment: I'd suggest adding a `.Publish(xs => xs.Buffer(() => xs.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(350.0))))` to prevent multiple subscriptions to your source observable.